# PHPPROBID payments

Tags: php

I am making a bank payment.

API request my bank:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <request version="1.0">
                <merchant>
                    <id>75482</id>
                    <signature>99730232b2f984c571507a0e74595e777afd0428</signature>
                </merchant>
                <data>
                    <oper>cmt</oper>
                    <wait>0</wait>
                    <test>0</test>
                    <payment id="1234567">
                        <prop name="b_card_or_acc" value="4627081718568608" />
                        <prop name="amt" value="1" />
                        <prop name="ccy" value="UAH" />
                        <prop name="details" value="test%20merch%20not%20active" />
                    </payment>
                </data>
            </request>
```

In PhpProBid every payment shold have formElements array like(Skrill):

```
   /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function formElements()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'id'      => self::PAY_TO_EMAIL,
                'value'   => $this->_data[self::PAY_TO_EMAIL],
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'language',
                'value'   => 'EN',
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'amount',
                'value'   => $this->getAmount(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'currency',
                'value'   => $this->getCurrency(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'merchant_fields',
                'value'   => self::TRANSACTION_FIELD,
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => self::TRANSACTION_FIELD,
                'value'   => $this->getTransactionId(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'detail1_description',
                'value'   => $this->getName(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'status_url',
                'value'   => $this->getIpnUrl(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'return_url',
                'value'   => $this->getSuccessUrl(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
            array(
                'id'      => 'cancel_url',
                'value'   => $this->getFailureUrl(),
                'element' => 'hidden',
            ),
        );
    }
```

After "Submit button" every form elements insert in  tag and make request
(Sreenshot)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fP9Fu.jpg)

But I need an XML structure.
I tried to create the structure with array elements, but they were still created with the  tag.
How can I make a request?

Comment: How do you try to create the xml structure?

Comment: yup, you've got your form now you need to convert the POST values to xml, what have you tried?

Comment: The script automatically takes an array from the formElements () method and forms a post request.

Comment: I try: 
            $post_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request version="1.0"><merchant>';
            $post_data .= '<id>155276</id>';
            $post_data .= '<signature>'.sha1(md5("dsfsf")).'</signature>';
            $post_data .= '</merchant><data>'.$data.'</data></request>';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pay_pb");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);